# Copy values and format in VBA macro excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new to this stuff i.e. writing macros in excel. I need to modify a macro where content is copied from 1 sheet to another but here only values are being copied whereas I would like to copy cell formatting as well. I have searched on a number of forums and tried to copy their formats but still no luck. May be I missing out something in my code.

strActiveSheet - Sheet from which content is copied

res - Sheet on which content is being pasted

```
With Sheets(strActiveSheet)
    .Select
    .Range(.Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 1), .Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 4)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    End With

'Paste
 Sheets(res).Select
 Cells(9, 1).Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

This code just copies the value. I have tried to use the following code but to no avail:

```
Sheets(res).Select
     Cells(9, 1).Select
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

If I use the following code, this will just copy the formatting but omit the values:

```
Sheets(res).Select
         Cells(9, 1).Select
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

May be I think I am not writing PasteSpecial code in correct format.

Can someone please help me to get the correct format for copying and pasting values as well as cell format from one sheet to another in VBA ?

Darren - I have edited my code and used as you have specified in your answer:

```
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim resSheet As Worksheet
Set resSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Demo")

With wrkSht
    .Range(.Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 1), .Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 4)).Copy
End With

With resSheet
    .Cells(9, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .Cells(9, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```

But still it is giving number as the format to my cells instead of the custom one that is assigned to cell in Sheet1.

Can you please help if I am missing out something in this code ?

Comment: You need to reply to my answer or write my user name with @ before it - otherwise I don't get the notification of an update.  Try changing `xlValues` to `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` in the PasteSpecial.

Comment: Still didn't work with xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Comment: I just tested your code - I had to give `DataStartRow` a value of 2 so it would copy from row 1.  It copied the formatting of `"Burt: "#,##0.00;[Red]-#,##0.00` without a problem.  What number format are you using and what are the values you're using it on?  Are the numbers formatted as text maybe?

Comment: My number format is "**"#,##0[$] as I need to display a number with asterik sign padded before the digits. e.g. **55

Comment: All I can think is your numbers are being treated as text.  I'm using `123`, `'546`, `-18` and `8465`.  With your formatting these are being copied as `**123`, `546` (this is formatted as text with the preceding `'`), `- **18` and `**8,465`.  So 546 is the only number not copying properly - do you have an apostrophe (`'`) before the numbers?

Comment: No, I am not using apostrophe (')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160515/discussion-between-user2091061-and-darren-bartrup-cook).

Comment: Sorry, can't... it's blocked at work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy everything you can copy and paste to the destination in the same command.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim DataStartRow As Long
    DataStartRow = 2

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim res As Worksheet
    Set res = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With wrkSht
        .Range(.Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 1), .Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 4)).Copy Destination:=res.Cells(9, 1)
    End With

'    Copy user selection
'    Selection.Copy Destination:=res.Cells(9, 1)

'    Paste to user selection
'    With wrkSht
'        .Range(.Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 1), .Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 4)).Copy Destination:=Selection
'    End With

End Sub
```

If you only want the values and cell formatting then you can use two PasteSpecial commands:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim DataStartRow As Long
    DataStartRow = 2

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim res As Worksheet
    Set res = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With wrkSht
        .Range(.Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 1), .Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 4)).Copy
    End With

    With res
        .Cells(9, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .Cells(9, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With

'    Copy user selection
'    Selection.Copy

'    Paste to user selection
'    With Selection
'        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
'        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
'    End With

End Sub
```

Note:  I haven't selected any cells in the code. You just have to reference them.

Comment: But I need to work on selection. Is there any way it can be handled for selected code ?

Comment: Your code doesn't work with the user selection - it selects a range of cells and pastes to it.  Is generally better to just paste to that range rather than select it first.  If, however, you want to work with the user selection - do you want to copy the selection or paste to the selection?  To paste to the selection use `.Range(.Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 1), .Cells(DataStartRow - 1, 4)).Copy Destination:=Selection` to copy from the selection use `Selection.Copy Destination:=res.Cells(9, 1)` (you can lose the `With..End With` block in that last case.

Comment: I've updated my answer with commented out code on copy/paste using the selection... I wouldn't trust the user to make the correct selection though (a lot of errors occur between the keyboard and chair).

Comment: Darren, I have edited my code and posted above. Can you please have a look and tell me if something is missing in it as I am still not getting the formatted value.